# Closure Not Keeping State Change

Tags: javascript

I thought I understood closures, but suddenly something simple does not seem to be working.

I've created a singleton using a closure. Here is a very minified version:

```
    Foobar = function() {
        var data = null;

        function init(obj) {
            data = obj;
        }

        return {
            init: init,
            currentValue: data
        }
    }();
```

Since it is a singleton, I expect that when I call the 'init' function, the value of 'data' will be changed in the one and only object that exists, and that value will still be avaliable in subsequent retrievals using 'currentValue'.

Here is my test:

```
    Foobar.init({id:3});
    var test = Foobar.currentValue;
```

When I step through this code in Firefox (F12), I can see that yes - 'data' is visible to the init function, and that it is changing that variable when I execute 'init'. However, after exiting the init function and returning to execute the second line of the test, var 'test' is assigned null (the original value when the singleton was created) instead of a copy of the object I passed to the 'init' function, as I expected.

Can someone clear up my confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are conflating two different things here-- that is, I think you are getting "Javascript passing objects by reference" and "Javascript closures" confused.

To answer your primary question-- the problem is that you are returning the value of your variable a single time at instantiation, and then never again.  So updating it won't change anything.  Instead, if you create a function that *returns* the value, you will see it being updated:

```js
Foobar = function() {
        var data = null;

        function init(obj) {
            data = obj;
        }

        function getCurrentValue() {
            return data; 
        }
  

        return {
            init: init,
            getCurrentValue: getCurrentValue
        }
    }();
    
    Foobar.init({id:3});
    console.log(Foobar.getCurrentValue());
```

NOW, *if* `data` was initialized as an *object*, and your `init` were to simply extend that object in some way, then the property itself would be updating as in your first example, because it would always be referring to the same object throughout its lifecycle:

```js
Foobar = function() {
        var data = {};

        function init(obj) {
            data.id = obj.id;
        }

        return {
            init: init,
            currentValue: data
        }
    }();
    
    Foobar.init({id:3});
    console.log(Foobar.currentValue);
```

Comment: SO says to avoid thanks, but in this case... Far too many times, SO answers focus on solving the bug in the tiny example case or special case situation, without answering the question. When that fails to help the next person, and they ask the question again to get a general-case answer to the actual question, they get dinged for duplicate questions. You've actually answered the question and taught me something rather than 'fixing the bug', which makes it less likely I'll repeat the mistake in the future. These kinds of answers are why I value SO.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from

```
var Foobar = function () {...}();
```

The statement can be broken down into

```
var Foobar;
Foobar = function () {...}();
```

At the first line, Global scope registered Foobar with no rhs reference, so Foobar is undefined at anywhere before the Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFEs).

On the second line, after IIFE is executed, Foobar is assigned to the IIFE's returned object as show below.

```
console.log(Foobar); // undefined
var Foobar = function () {...}();
console.log(Foobar); // Object {currentValue: null, init: function}
```

The IIFE's returned object at this point can visualise as

[image: Click to show Diagram of Initial Foobar]

Then, when *Foobar.init({id:3});* is executed. Foobar's init will ask for rhs reference, which happen to be IIFE's init. The init has closure over data and eventually set **data** to *{id:3}*

[image: Click to show Diagram of after Foobar.init]

Therefore

```
var test = Foobar.currentValue;
```

is clearly still a *null* value as its initial state.

To make it meet our expectation. There are at least two possible solution here as [anied](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6831341/anied) had mentioned.

1. Creating another function in IIFE with closure over **data** in order to
   retrieve them.
2. Instead of assign **data** to a new object, IIFE's init directly
   manipulate the same object itself.

Comment: I appreciate the diagramming. You also have taken the time to answer the question instead of just fixing the bug.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that placing data in the object returned saves the value at the time the function executed first - which is null.

In order to read the current value of the data variable, currentValue must be a function, like init.

```
Foobar = function() {
        var data = null;

        function init(obj) {
                data = obj;
        }

        function currentValue() {
                return data;
        }

        return {
                init: init,
                currentValue: currentValue
        }
}();
console.log(Foobar);
Foobar.init({id:3});
var test = Foobar.currentValue();
console.log(Foobar,test);
```